# get sum of repeating form fields (CF7, PHP, WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, sum, contact-form-7, calculation

I'm using the [repeating field plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-repeatable-fields/) for Contact Form 7, and want to use it to create a budget table where users can add an item to their budget, and have a total display at the bottom.

The repeater fields that I want to add up are being given a name "expense-price__1", "expense-price__2" etc, with the number being added on for each repeat:

```
<div class="form-group expense-price"><input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-number wpcf7-validates-as-number form-control" name="expense-price__1" type="number" value="" placeholder="0.00" min="" max="" step="" aria-invalid="false"></div>
```

I've found an example filter for Contact Form 7 which is similar but doesn't account for the repeating fields. (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-contact-form-7-do-simple-math/)

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', function ( $data ) {
// Set this to the form ID.
$form_id = wpcf7-f2698-p2696-o1;

/*
 * This is necessary, which ensures that we are filtering/modifying only
 * the data submitted via the form with the ID of $form_id and not all 
forms!
 */
$form = wpcf7_get_current_contact_form();
if ( ! $form || $form_id != $form->id() ) {
    return $data;
}
$data['sum'] = //(calculation here)
return $data;
 } );

function grant_budget_shortcode() {
echo $data['sum'];
}
add_shortcode('budget-total', 'grant_budget_shortcode');
```

Is there anyway I can calculate the sum of all the name="expense-price__#" fields?

Thanks

Comment: `$form_id = wpcf7-f2698-p2696-o1;` should be `$form_id = 'wpcf7-f2698-p2696-o1';`

Comment: Thank you, I thought so.